# Usage of nc -q with milliseconds

Tags: bash, tcp, netcat

**NC -q option**

I control my receiver over LAN using this command:

`printf '$CMD\r\n' | nc 192.168.1.106 23`

Receiver send response to command but netcat is already closed. If i use command:
`printf '$CMD\r\n' | nc 192.168.1.106 23 -q 1` 
i get correct response, but 1 second lasts like forever. Tried some tricks like 0.1 or 100ms but i get error for invalid timer.

How can i force nc to wait for response or force it to wait small amount of time?

Answer (score 2):

`man` is your friend:

```
$ man nc
```

> «Options taking a time assume seconds. Append 'ms' for milliseconds,
>   's' for seconds, 'm' for minutes, or 'h' for hours (e.g. 500ms).»

edit: for nc 7.12

Comment: i have 6.40 version. Any idea there?

Comment: should work too, according to this man page, that has the same info for nc 6.40: http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/nc/

Comment: That man page points to _ncat_ command which does not offer **-q** option.
When i try 
`~$  printf '?p\r\n' | nc 192.168.1.106 23 -q 10ms` **Result:**
_nc: quit timer invalid: 10ms_

Comment: I guess it won't work then. If you really need that option, and in case you can't update it in the system you're using, you may consider trying to compile a more recent version from source and then using that one.